# matrix print convert from input one by one to input space-separated

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, matrix

I have this code that prints a matrix of inputed values. Now the values are inputed one by one, but I want to convert it to to be space-sepatrated input. I have tried many ways, but non worked, how can I do it?

```
print("This program prints a matrix in aligned rows and columns")
while True:
    try:
        nbrRows = int(input("What is the number of rows: "))
        if nbrRows <= 0:
            print("The number of rows cannot be negative or zero")
            continue
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("You did not enter an integer value")
    continue
while True:
    try:
        nbrCols = int(input("What is the number of columns: "))
        if nbrCols <= 0:
            print("The number of columns cannot be negative or zero")
            continue
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("You did not enter an integer value")
        continue

print("Please enter the elements one by one at the prompts")
nbrElements = nbrRows * nbrCols
count = 0
outputString = ""

for i in range(nbrRows):
    for j in range(nbrCols):
        while True:
            try:
                elem = int(input("? "))
                break
            except:
                print("Please enter an integer value")
        outputString += str(elem) + "\t"
    outputString += "\n"

print(outputString)
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: looks like your code is working fine. It produces output spaces separated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by asking user to enter elements by comma separated and then splitting them to print output.

```
elem = input ("Please enter the elements comma separate : ")
element = elem.split(",")
nbrElements = nbrRows * nbrCols
count = 0
outputString = ""


for i in range(nbrRows):
    for j in range(nbrCols):
        for e in element :
            outputString += str(e) + "\t"
        outputString += "\n"
```

output

```
This program prints a matrix in aligned rows and columns
What is the number of rows: 2
What is the number of columns: 2
Please enter the elements comma seperated : 1,2,3,4
1   2   3   4   
1   2   3   4   
1   2   3   4   
1   2   3   4
```

Comment: Yes it works, but as you see you need to input the elements one by one, I would like to have it to be inputed in one go seperated by a space. I was unable to do so.

Comment: You can ask user  for comma separated input and then split them to print output.